# How do I select a range of cells in a table top copy using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

What is the syntax for copying a range of cells from a table using VBA? Ideally it would be a structured reference, using the column names and table row numbers. And be able to select any sized rectangle of cells from that table, not just one row or one column.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this... Adapt the resize rows, columns column based on your requirement.

Resize(Row,Column)

```
Range("Table1").Cells(1).Resize(5, 2).Copy
```